# Compare first column of a file with value if matched get the record

Tags: awk, files

Can any one help me with the below scenario?
I have a reference file has data below:

```
file_id|file_name
1|file1.txt
2|file2.txt
3|file3.txt
```

I have a script which accepts input as file_id and fetches the 2nd column.

```
file_id=$1
header=$(awk -v a=$file_id -F '~' "$1==a {print $2}" \
/test/data/shared/dev/SrcFiles/datawarehouse/poc/file_ref_master.txt)
```

This is giving me a blank value instead of the file name.

Output:

```
vi file_lookup_poc.sh
$ sh -x file_lookup_poc.sh 1

file_id=1
++ awk -v a=$file_id -F '~' '$1==a {print $7}' /test/data/infa_shared/dev/poc/file_ref_master.txt
header=
echo
```

Comment: Double-quotes don't prevent the shell from interpreting $1 and $2. Use single quotes instead. Also, I don't understand why you use the tilde as field separator.

Comment: Since your fields are `|`-separated, don't tell awk they're `~`-separated instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

script

```
#!/bin/bash
m=$1
awk -F "|" -v m="$m" '$1 == m{print $2}' filename
```

output

```
sh script.sh 1
file1.txt
 
sh script.sh 2
file2.txt

sh script.sh 3
file3.txt
```

Comment: Thanku it worked perfect

Comment: @daturmgirl see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for how to accept an answer to a question. Having said that, `-F'|'` is undefined behavior and so YMMV with what any awk will do with that, it needs to be `-F'[|]'` (or `-F'\\|'` if you prefer doubling backslashes) instead.